# what is timezone that schedule (configuration option in elasticsearch input logstash) is based on?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have following configuration in my logstash pipeline, I want to schedule to run the query for specific hour every day (schedule => "*/5 * * * *" already working) , but it doesn't work. I have a distributed environment that logstash and elasticsearch servers are seperated..two questions :
1.where the schedule reads date from ?
2.what is the timezone used for scheduling?

```
    input{
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => "ip:9200"
            index => "indexname"
            user => "user"
            password => "elastic"
            query => '{ "query": { "query_string": { "query": "*" } } }'
            schedule => "*/5 17 * * *"   #Specifies how often the query should be executed. In this case, it's set to run every 5 minutes
            size => 1500   #Specifies the maximum number of documents to retrieve per query
            scroll => "5m" #Specifies how long Elasticsearch should keep the search context open for the query. In this case, it's set to 5 minutes
            docinfo => true
          }
    }
filter {}
 
        
    output {
      if "API_REQUEST" in [message] {
        jdbc {
          driver_jar_path => '/usr/share/logstash/vendor/jar/jdbc/mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre8.jar'
          connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://ip:1433;databaseName=izdb;user=user;password=pass;ssl=false;trustServerCertificate=true"
          enable_event_as_json_keyword => true
          statement => [
    "INSERT INTO Transaction (document_id, logLevel, timestamp) VALUES (?,?,?)",
            "document_id",
            "logLevel",
            "timestamp"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You're sure that the scheduler and timezone are the cause of your problem ? maybe this is related to the es query ? or the output processing steps ?

Comment: When I set it to every 5 minute , everything works fine